# Monitor multiple desktop remotely continuously

Tags: 16.04, remote, remote-access, monitoring, system-monitor

### Scenario

I have 3 BareBone system with following specifications (from SystemInfo page) that is used for some basic work in office such as Data Entry, SEO...:

- Intel Celeron CPU J1800 @ 2.41GHz x 2
- 3.7 GB RAM
- Intel Bay Trail Graphics (Intel GMA 4000 HD as mentioned on vendor website)
- 32 GB SSD (and that's all the internal space, NO SPINNING DISK)
- Ubuntu 16.04 64Bit

I hope I made the right choice by removing Windows 7 and installing Ubuntu 16.04 as I don't have much HDD space. There are 2 more development System which currently is on Windows but I am slowly migrating both developers to Ubuntu.

I have some experience in Linux. But I am far from being a SysAdmin Expert!

### Problem

To make sure that I made a right choice and assist the developers and call center/data entry operators on the fly I need a way with which I can get all the information about system that I can remotely such as

- Processes
- RAM, Processor and SWAP status
- System UP and Down time (Event Manager data)

To assist, I can further use SSH (or even TeamViewer) but for observation of system quality and how a user is using it, I need my hands on as much info I can on the real time!

I have a cloud ubuntu system on AWS-EC2.I can use this server that will collect data from systems continuously.

### QUESTION

How can I continuously monitor these systems continuously?

Comment: All of these can be acquired with various command-line tools (e. g. `ps`, `free`, `uptime`) over SSH. What else do you need exactly?

Comment: @DavidFoerster sorry for late reply! I need continuous data not just when I am using SSH with them!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to clarify that and narrow your question? That will also trigger a vote to reopen the question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster can you check, is it better now?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks. But any idea on how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the desktop sharing software that comes pre-installed with Ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)